# How do I add padding around a title in plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am converting my `ggplot2` graph into plotly. I'd like to add the title manually, since I want to leave space to add a subtitle afterwards - which `ggplotly` doesn't do on its own.

```
g <- retention_cohorts %>% 
  ggplot(aes(relative_week, round(percent,2), label=relative_week)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,24,4),
                     labels = seq(1,6)
  ) +
  geom_text(nudge_y = .02) +
  # geom_text_repel() +
  labs(
    # title = "Purchasing Retention Analysis",
    subtitle = "Customers who order at least one item each week",
    y = "Ratio of Customers",
    x = "Relative Month"
  ) + theme_light()
```

The [docs](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-title-pad-b) say that I can set the padding with pad, but when I add it to the `layout` function, it serves an error saying that it is an invalid argument.

```
ggplotly(g) %>%    
  layout(
    title = "My Title",
    pad = list(b = 90, l = 130, r = 50 ))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title should be created like shown below.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")%>%    
  layout(title = list(text = "My Title",pad = list(b = 90, l = 130, r = 50 )))
p
```

Where the `title` is a list with values `text` and `pad`. Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

Comment: Here's the documentation reference: (R) https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-title-pad (Python) https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-title-pad

Comment: The padding values are `b` = bottom, `t` = top, `l` = left, `r` = right.